# CreateElements push to Array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some problems understanding this code, maybe I'm missing some basics...

**JS:**

```
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
let squares = []

function createGrid() {
    //create 100 elements with a for loop
    for (let i=0; i < 100; i++) {

    const square = document.createElement('div')

    square.classList.add('square')

    grid.appendChild(square)

    squares.push(square)
    }
}

squares[10].classList.add('snake') //magic happens
```

**CSS**:

```
.snake {
    background-color: green;
}
```

How come *squares* array elements affect dynamically on *square*. (*squares[0].classList.add('snake')*)?

Why putting style on array elements would affect the created elements?

*squares* should be a "static" array?

Thanks...

Comment: Because JS passes objects by reference … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

> How come squares array elements affect dynamically on square.

Appending an element somewhere in the DOM doesn't remove it from the array.

The array continues to hold a reference to the DOM element.